# CNN (Conv2d) cannot reshape array of size 12402 into shape (318,39,39,1)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, reshape, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset on which I train a CNN model. My dataset contain 398 samples and 330 features, I reduced features to 39 with `ExtraTreeclassifier()`. I create a model with `Conv1d` and that's work fine, but I want to create a CNN with `Conv2d`.
How can I reshape my `x_train` and `x_test` for `Conv2D`?

```py
x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0],x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[1],1)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0],x_test.shape[1],x_test.shape[1],1)
```

Results in :

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12402 into shape (318,39,39,1)
```

Comment: what dimension are the 39 features actually in? are those 2d features, if so, should simply using them as 39x39x1 work or should you even use a conv2d for this task?

Answer (score 1):

Here number of input nodes are not equal to the output node.
What does it mean?
`12402` is your actual image node and you reshape node are `(318*39*39*1)==483678` which is not equal to `12402`

Reshape is only allowed when the number of nodes are equal. You have to do reshape in such a way that the product of all dim equal to `12402`

Check out the similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61091607/valueerror-cant-split-axis-of-size-85-into-pieces-of-size-2-2-1-20-keras-tra/61092590#61092590).

Comment: I edited your answer, but it still needs better wording. what did you mean by node? I leave further elaboration on that to you as I can not act on my assumption about your intention. Good luck